# Python return message with multiple word list

Tags: python, discord

I am making a very simple bot on discord that return a message if the bot reads simple word, whoever sends it.
I would like the bot to return a 2nd message if he reads another word in a second list.

As it is, if someone type "WORD 2", it return perfecty "MESSAGE 2" but it's not working for "WORD 1" and "MESSAGE 1", nothing happen.

My code is the following :

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

class Myclient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        word_list = ['WORD 1']
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        messageContent = message.content
        if len(messageContent) > 0:
            for word in word_list:
                if word in messageContent:
                    await message.channel.send('MESSAGE 1 @everyone')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        word_list = ['WORD2']
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        messageContent = message.content
        if len(messageContent) > 0:
            for word in word_list:
                if word in messageContent:
                    await message.channel.send('MESSAGE 2 @everyone')

client = Myclient()
client.run('my token here')
```

Comment: You seem to have overwritten your first on_message method with the second one.

Comment: Did you mean to have a single method with 'word_list = ['WORD1','WORD2']'?

Comment: No because this would mean 1 message if the bot read either of the word (WORD 1 or WORD 2).
For me, I would want 2 different message depending on the WORD the bot reads
WORD 1 ---> MESSAGE 1
WORD 2 ---> MESSAGE 2

Comment: Please don't just say 'no'. There are ways round these things. If you know that WORD1 has been detected, then you know that you should reply with MESSAGE1 etc. You've indicated as much in your reply above: match the word found to the required message to send.

Comment: Indeed, I am sorry for the way i answered. Thanks to the answer bellow, I found a way around it by using word_list1 and world_list2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to simply have a `dict` which maps matching words to response messages:

```py
    async def on_message(self, message):
        response_map = {'WORD1': 'MESSAGE 1 @everyone', 'WORD2':'MESSAGE 2 @everyone'}
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        messageContent = message.content
        if len(messageContent) > 0:
            for word, message in response_map:
                if word in messageContent:
                    await message.channel.send(message)
```

Comment: I found a solution (see bellow) but I will give that a try too. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two `on_message` functions like that; the second definition will overwrite the first. For this kind of functionality you must have one `on_message` method that checks what the message is, and then depending on what the message content is, does whatever you want.

Comment: Indeed, it was the problem. I found a solution thanks to your clue. Should I post the solution bellow ?

Comment: Yeah, you should update your post to have the solution below it so that it can help others!

Comment: Emphasis on _like that_, you **can** have two different listeners to the same event in different cogs

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry in advance if this is not a good way to code but I am very new and inexperimented.
However, that solved it for me :

```
    async def on_message(self, message):
        word_list1 = ['WORD1']
        word_list2 = ['WORD2']
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        messageContent = message.content
        if len(messageContent) > 0:
            for word in word_list1:
                if word in messageContent:
                    await message.channel.send('MESSAGE 1 @everyone')
        if message.author == self.user:
                return
        messageContent = message.content
        if len(messageContent) > 0:
            for word in word_list2:
                if word in messageContent:
                    await message.channel.send('MESSAGE 2 @everyone')
```